# Forward multipart POST request from asp.net core controller to another project that deployed on same server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

We have two projects 1 is .net core and another is also on .net core but that contain api.

The We have redirected get request from the controller to other poject. But I am unable to send Multipart post reques to another project on the same host.

my Class for redirect request are follows:

```
public RelayedActionResult(HttpClient client, HttpRequest request)
    {
        this.client = client;
        this.request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod(request.Method), request.Path + request.QueryString);

        foreach (var hdr in request.Headers)
        {
            switch (hdr.Key.ToLowerInvariant())
            {
                case "x-auth-token":
                    this.request.Headers.Add("X-Auth-Token", (IEnumerable<string>)hdr.Value);
                    break;
            }
        }

        this.request.Content = new StreamContent(request.Body);
        this.request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(request.ContentType);
    }

    public async Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
    {
        using (var input = await client.SendAsync(request))
        {
            //To Do So
        }
    }
```

it works when the request is for getting data but Not working if Post multi part data to another server. The Form data not reached to another server.

Comment: this .net not angular

Comment: Actually, I am sending post request from my .net core angular project, an this is my controller to send a request from one server to another one.

Comment: What @Pranay was trying to say is that Angular is a frontend technology, and your question is about backend code. All that matters is that you have a multipart POST. The frontend technology that's sending it doesn't matter, which it seems you already knew considering you haven't provided any Angular code.

Comment: @John Thanks to correct me. I am new with this technology so that leads me wrong in wording.

Comment: -No worries :-)

Comment: @PranayRana Could you have any solution for me?

Comment: not getting much from this , can you please explain in detail,

Comment: @PranayRana What we are doing we have API published on port ex: localhost:6000/api/ and we have another project that contains angular website. With the above code I am able to fetch all get requests on the url localhost/api/ (without port) but in the case of Post the Form data not receving at the  localhost/api/. please let me know if I am not clear enough